# Dealing with currency values in PIG - pigstorage

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-pig

I have 2 column CSV file loaded in HDFS. Column 1 is a Model name, column 2 is a price in $. `Example - Model: IE33, Price: $52678.00`

When I run the following script, the price values all return as a two digit result example $52.

```
ultraPrice = LOAD '/user/maria_dev/UltrasoundPrice.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (
Model, Price);

dump ultraPrice;
```

All my values are between $20000 and $60000. I don't know why it is being cut off.

If I change the CSV file and remove the $ from the price values everything works fine, but I know there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in your load statement you are not specifying the datatype.By default the model and price will be of type bytearray and hence the discrepancy.

You can either remove the $ from the csv file or load the data as chararray and replace the $ sign and cast it into float.

```
A = LOAD '/user/maria_dev/UltrasoundPrice.csv' USING TextLoader() as (line:chararray);
A1 = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(line,'([^a-zA-Z0-9.,\\s]+)','');
B = FOREACH A1 GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT($0,','));
B1 = FOREACH B GENERATE $0 as Model,(float)$1 as Price;
DUMP B1;
```